# Flatlist onEndReached endless loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-listview

I am using `state` to store the following data.

```
state = {
    refresh: true,
    isFetching: true,
    showLoadingBottom: false,
    data: []
};
```

on `componentDidMount` I manually call a function `_fetchData` which loads data into `this.state.data`.

When the flatlist is scrolled to the end it fires `_fetchData` twice which ends up returning the same data twice ( which is another problem, why does it fire twice? ).

Once the flatlist reaches the end ie, no more data is returned from the server, it goes into an endless loop since the `onEndReached` continuously fires over and over again even though no new data is returned from the server and `this.state.data` remains the same.

This is my `render` code

```
render() {

    return (

        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1
            }}>

            <FlatList

                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={this.state.refresh}
                        onRefresh={() => {
                            this.setState({
                                refresh: true
                            }, this._fetchData);
                        }}
                        title={"Pull To Refresh"}
                        tintColor={darkGrey}
                        titleColor={darkGrey}/>
                }

                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                onEndReached={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        showLoadingBottom: true
                    }, () => {
                        this._fetchData();
                    });

                }}

                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}

                data={this.state.data}

                ListFooterComponent={() => {
                    return (
                        this.state.showLoadingBottom &&
                        <View style={{padding: 10}}>
                            <ActivityIndicator size="small" color={colorAccent}/>
                        </View>
                    );
                }}

                renderItem={this._renderItem}

                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}

                removeClippedSubviews={true}

            />

        </View>

    );
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure out the solution?

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar problem. In my case it is because the `ListFooterComponent`.

If you render the `ListFooterComponent` with this pattern or equivalent

```
onEndReachedThreshold={x} // for any x >= 0
ListFooterComponent={() => {
  if (isDataFetching) {
    return <SomeComponentWithSomeHeight />
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}}
```

It will trigger `onEndReached` infinitely when the user scrolls down the end of the list (or if your content is not longer than the list's visibility area).

And it is because the presence and absence of the `<SomeComponentWithSomeHeight />` affects the height of the content and thus triggers the `endReached` re-calculation.

[image: FlatList onEndReached infinite loop]

And following are the possible solution I can think of.

1. Use negative `onEndReachedThreshold` that is always "higher" than the height of the `ListFooterComponent`. But I don't like this solution because it is difficult to know the "higher" (it is relative to the FlatList's visibility area). And the negative `onEndReachedThreshold` may cause some issue on Android.
2. Implement your own loading overlay outside of the `FlatList` so that the loading component does not affect the content height.
3. Set `opacity = 0` to hide the `ListFooterComponent` instead of returning `undefined`, so that it is always there and the content height does not change when it becomes visible.

```
ListFooterComponent={() => {
  return (
    <View style={{ opacity: isDataFetching ? 1 : 0 }}>
      <SomeComponentWithSomeHeight />
    </View>
  );
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution that can maybe be changed to suit other peoples needs:
Basically the important parts are `onEndReached={this.state.moreData && this.retrieveMore}`. So you can test inside your `onEndReached` function weather there is anymore data (In my case if we only return 1 object i know it's finished) then set state `this.state.moreData` to false.

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
        data={Object.values(this.state.documentData)}
        // Render Items
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ItemSelector
                item={item}
                onPress={() => {this.selectItem(item)}}
            />
        )}
        // On End Reached (Takes in a function)
        onEndReached={this.state.moreData && this.retrieveMore}
        // How Close To The End Of List Until Next Data Request Is Made
        onEndReachedThreshold={1}
        ListEmptyComponent={
            <Text>No jobs to show</Text>
        }
    />
</SafeAreaView>

retrieveMore = async () => {
    try {

        // Set State: Refreshing
        this._isMounted && this.setState({ refreshing: true });

        fbDb.ref('job')
            .orderByKey()
            .startAt(this.state.lastVisible) //Start at the last item we found
            .limitToFirst(this.state.limit) //Limit queries returned per page
            .once('value', snapshot => {

                //check if we got a result
                if(snapshot.numChildren() > 1){

                    .....
                    this._isMounted && this.setState({
                        documentData: newstate,
                        lastVisible: lastVisible,
                        refreshing: false, //Hide loading icon
                    });
                } else {
                    this._isMounted && this.setState({
                        refreshing: false, //Hide loading icon
                        moreData: false
                    });
                }
            });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using  a component that is being rendered when you are loading data, right? So your flatlist needs to rerender. You meed to make sure you only call you fetch method once even thou your end is reached multiple times.

Comment: How do you suggest I go about doing that? What can I add to my existing code that would allow me to do that?

Comment: You already know if you are showing the bottom loader inthe state. So only trigger fetchdata if it is not shown should suffice. Exit early from the onEndReached if showLoadingBottom is trueish and do what you're currently doing otherwise.